# Failsafe tests results in sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have just separated the unit tests and the integration tests. I wanted to separate the coverage results from UT and from IT.

I followed [this tutorial](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-maven-sonar-failsafe-and-jacoco/) and it works (Thanks [@JohnDobie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365383/john-dobie)).

[image: sonar coverage test results]

Sonar displays the separate code coverage results and the unit test success (upper right). But how can i get the integration test success in sonar ?

Comment: Should probably be asked at/migrated to superuser, no?

Comment: @TheBlastOne I don't know, there isn't any sonar tag on superuser.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I disagree, Sonar questions are usually related to programming. I doubt the people at superuser can answer questions related to unit testing and maven configuraton.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Awaiting for an implementation in sonar of the IT execution results (see the [@Fabrice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976155/fabrice-sonar-team) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499778/1594933)). I have found a workaround in [this tutorial](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-maven-sonar-failsafe-and-jacoco/). The idea is :

*`... fool Sonar to show test success for both unit and integration tests together by instructing Failsafe to store its test reports to the same directory as Surefire instead of the default failsafe-reports.`*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The result is not perfect because all the tests result are shown in the unit test widget. But i really don't want to check the IT tests results in the ci server. I want an all-in-one dashboard for my project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IT execution results are not pushed nor displayed in Sonar.

This is something we may add in the future, but we first focused on coverage as this is the most important after all. (execution results are usually monitored via CI software on CI servers)

Comment: It is a pity to have to check the the ci server since sonar is a "All in one" tool.

Comment: I 100% agree with @gontard.

Comment: Well, test execution results are really useless in SonarQube because you should always have 100% of success (and so 0 errors and 0 failurs) => if you run a SonarQube analysis whereas your project has regressions, you are really missing the point of continuous integration.

Comment: See also the corresponding feature request: [https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-45](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-45)

Comment: You may argue which metrics are useful or not, but at least the statistics displayed for unit and integration tests should be consistent!  I currently have 60 successful unit tests covering 30% of the code and an unknown number of (in fact failing) integration tests covering 25% of the code....

Comment: Consider an enterprise with multiple development teams, a large number of projects, and a separate quality assurance or internal audit team that is reviewing projects for a variety of health metrics, including test coverage. It is very useful for such a team to have one tool with this information, particularly if the auditors are not developers, are sometimes not technical, and are less familiar with CI builds. Plus, SonarQube does such a nice job of maintaining history, also important to auditors.

Comment: Update for the [https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-45](SONARJAVA-45): It was closed as WONTFIX in Oct 2016. I'm being a nitpick here but why are unit test results displayed while integration tests are not? If the reason is "don't analyse failed builds" shouldn't the same rationale apply for both?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Hm, interesting. StackOverflow has done something with the link... the same URL still works: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-45