# will maven failsafe report in surefire folder show test cases failing in sonar?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By using this maven configuration will I be able to view the Integration test cases run , list of integration test cases failed?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `mvn sonar:sonar`, then the failsafe plugin should be part of the build and you should get the report you want since sonar created the data for the reports, first.

Related:

- http://blog.javabien.net/2012/11/23/combine-surefire-tests-and-failsafe-tests-coverage/
- [Failsafe tests results in sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496856/failsafe-tests-results-in-sonar)