# How to show Integration Test Statistics?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Im using SonarQube v6.4. I'm aware that all types of tests (Unit Tests, Integration Tests etc) have been merged together as overall coverage.

However, on the interface I can see statistics for only Unit tests, Is there a way to get the statistics for other types of tests?

Example of statistics available only for unit test

- Unit Test Errors
- Unit Test Failures
- Skipped Unit Tests
- Unit Test Success (%)
- Unit Test Duration

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this feature is not supported in Sonarqube. A ticket opened for this [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-45) has already been closed as "Won't Fix" by the Sonarqube Team.

For a workaround you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496856/failsafe-tests-results-in-sonar)

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube no longer distinguishes between different types of tests. Integration tests, Smoke Tests, Medium Tests, Regression Tests, etc. - all are now called "Unit Tests". This new naming is indeed misleading...

---

For to see the values navigate to your project, click on the "Measures" tab ("All" page) and scroll down to "Coverage". There you will find the current tests measure values.

Starting from version 6.6 of SonarQube you will be able to show graphs for any metric (see [SonarQube's own SonarQube](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/project/activity?custom_metrics=test_failures&graph=custom&id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) instance with 6.6-SNAPSHOT installed).

Navigate to any SonarQube project, click on the tab "Activity", select "Custom" from the drop down and click on "Add metric". There you can choose "Unit Test Errors", "Skipped Unit Tests", etc.

Comment: Thanks @slartidan. I'm aware of this and I use this feature already. But in my use case I have more than Unit tests and the only statistics I can see are only for unit tests.

Note: The new feature you mentioned above will be available from v6.5

Comment: @philip Charts will be available in v6.5, but custom charts only in v6.6.

Comment: Thanks. but when I click on the Unit Test, it shows only a list of my Unit test, other types of tests are missing

Comment: @philip Then this probably means, that SonarQube is not aware of your other tests. :( This seems to be a build pipeline issue - you will have to see how to include those other tests in the analysis.

Comment: I just added an image for clarity, All the tests were used for calculating the overall coverage (57.8%), just that these tests do not show when I click on the "Unit Test" statistics link and there is no extra links where they can be seen

Comment: @philip So you click on the "Unit Tests" link, right below the big `112` number, but end up with an empty list?

Comment: I click on the link but did not find all tests used in calculating the overall code coverage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149569/discussion-between-slartidan-and-philip).